# RunnableGraph to wait for multiple response from source

Tags: java-8, playframework, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using Akka in Play Controller and performing ask() to a actor by name **publish** , and internal publish actor performs ask to multiple actors and passes reference of sender. The controller actor needs to wait for response from multiple actors and create a list of response.

Please find the code below. but this code is only waiting for 1 response and latter terminating. Please suggest

```
// Performs ask to publish actor
Source<Object,NotUsed> inAsk = Source.fromFuture(ask(publishActor,service.getOfferVerifyRequest(request).getPayloadData(),1000));

final Sink<String, CompletionStage<String>> sink = Sink.head();

        final Flow<Object, String, NotUsed> f3 = Flow.of(Object.class).map(elem -> {
            log.info("Data in Graph is " +elem.toString());
            return elem.toString();
        });
        RunnableGraph<CompletionStage<String>> result = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
                GraphDSL.create(
                        sink , (builder , out) ->{
                            final Outlet<Object> source = builder.add(inAsk).out();
                            builder
                                    .from(source)
                                    .via(builder.add(f3))
                                    .to(out); // to() expects a SinkShape
                            return ClosedShape.getInstance();
                        }
                ));

        ActorMaterializer mat = ActorMaterializer.create(aSystem);

        CompletionStage<String> fin = result.run(mat);


        fin.toCompletableFuture().thenApply(a->{
                log.info("Data is "+a);
                return true;
        });

        log.info("COMPLETED CONTROLLER ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several responses `ask` won't cut it, that is only for a single request-response where the response ends up in a `Future`/`CompletionStage`.

There are a few different strategies to wait for all answers:

One is to create an intermediate actor whose only job is to collect all answers and then when all partial responses has arrived respond to the original requestor, that way you could use ask to get a single aggregate response back.

Another option would be to use `Source.actorRef` to get an `ActorRef` that you could use as `sender` together with `tell` (and skip using `ask`). Inside the stream you would then take elements until some criteria is met (time has passed or elements have been seen). You may have to add an operator to mimic the ask response timeout to make sure the stream fails if the actor never responds.

There are some other issues with the code shared, one is creating a materializer on each request, these have a lifecycle and will fill up your heap over time, you should rather get a materializer injected from play.

With the given logic there is no need whatsoever to use the GraphDSL, that is only needed for complex streams with multiple inputs and outputs or cycles. You should be able to compose operators using the Flow API alone (see for example https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#defining-and-running-streams )